# Difference between A[1:3][0:2] and A[1:3,0:2]

Tags: python, numpy

I can't figure out the difference between these two kinds of indexing. It seems like they should produce the same results but they do not. Any explanation?

Answer (score 7):

`A[1:3, 0:2]` takes rows `1-3` and columns `0-2` thus returning a `2x2` array.

`A[1:3][0:2]` first takes rows `1-3` *and from this subarray* takes the rows `0-2`, resulting in a `2xn` array where `n` is the original number of columns.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [4]: a[1:3,0:2]
Out[4]: 
array([[4, 5],
       [8, 9]])

In [5]: a[1:3]
Out[5]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [6]: a[1:3][0:2]

Out[6]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

The equivalent of `A[1:3,0:2]` using two `[]` is: `A[1:3][:,0:2]`:

```
In [7]: a[1:3][:,0:2]
Out[7]: 
array([[4, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```

Where `:` means "all the rows". So you are first selecting the rows via `[1:3]` and then, from all the rows select columns `0-2`.

Answer (score 3):

`A[1:3][0:2]` means first apply `[1:3]` on A, and then apply `[0:2]` on the array returned from the first step, so both slicing are only applied on the rows. OTOH `A[1:3, 0:2]` means apply `1:3` on the rows and `0:2` on columns, ie. get second and third row only and get only the first two columns of those rows.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

>>> a[1:3][0:2]
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> a[1:3]                 #Get 2nd and 3rd row.
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> _[0:2]                 #Get the first two rows of the last array.
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

>>> a[1:3, 0:2]
array([[4, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```